# Resolving dependencies in the ConfigureMultitenantContainer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, ioc-container, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to resolve `ITenantIdentificationStrategy` in the `ConfigureMultitenantContainer` but I am having `An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll`.

I have registered the `TenantResolverStrategy` in the `ConfigureContainer`:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
  builder.RegisterType<TenantResolverStrategy>().As<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
}
```

I want to resolve the `ITenantIdentificationStrategy` in the `ConfigureMultitenantContainer`:

```
public static MultitenantContainer ConfigureMultitenantContainer(IContainer container)
{
  var strategy = container.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
  var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(strategy, container);
  // mtc.ConfigureTenant("a", cb => cb.RegisterType<TenantACustom>().As<ITenantCustom>());
  return mtc;
}
```

However it is throwing `An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll`.

My `ITenantIdentificationStrategy` is implemented this way:

```
public class TenantResolverStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
{
  public TenantResolverStrategy(
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
    IMemoryCache memoryCache,
    TenantEntity tenantEntity
  )
  {
    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
    this.tenantEntity = tenantEntity;
  }

  public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenantId)
  {
    tenantId = null;

    var context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    var hostName = context?.Request?.Host.Value;

    tenantEntity = GetTenant(hostName);
    if (tenantEntity != null)
    {
      tenantId = tenantEntity.TenantCode;
    }

    return (tenantId != null || tenantId == (object)"");
  }
}
```

And I register the `ConfigureMultitenantContainer` in the `Program.cs` as follows:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacMultitenantServiceProviderFactory(Startup.ConfigureMultitenantContainer))
```

I couldn't resolve other dependencies which I register in the `ConfigureContainer` as well. Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

Comment: I suspect that one of your objects can't be resolved and that is causing the issue. Can you get non-multitenanted container to work and resolve you the objects you need?

Comment: I think you are kinda right. I am not able to resolve DbContext but I am able to resolve other dependency that is not related to DbContext.

Comment: After further check, if the `ITenantIdentificationStrategy` does not have dependency related to DbContext, the DbContext is able to resolved afterwards in other classes.

As I need to identify the tenant based on the hostname which is stored in the DbContext, how could I do that in other way?

Comment: Looking at the error message, it is actually unable to resolve the DbContextOption. `An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll: 'An exception was thrown while activating WebApi.Saas.TenantResolverStrategy2 -> Data.System.Databases.SystemDbContext -> λ:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions[[Data.System.Databases.SystemDbContext, Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`. But how can I resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that may be causing you trouble here.

First, I see your tenant ID strategy is *not a singleton*.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<TenantResolverStrategy>().As<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
```

That's trouble, because every single resolution from the tenant ID strategy is going to go through a single instance of the tenant ID strategy. It's going to be cached. However, resolving the strategy is going to resolve different values and be misleading.

Consider:

```cs
var strategy = container.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
// The multitenant container is CACHING THIS.
var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(container, strategy);
// Now, later on you maybe resolve another instance of the strategy:
var anotherInstance = mtc.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
// Or from the root:
var thirdInstance = container.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();

// OH NO! strategy != anotherInstance != thirdInstance
// These ARE NOT THE SAME INSTANCE. Tenant determination may CHANGE
// based on which one of these is used.
```

**Make your tenant ID strategy a singleton.**

Next, since the strategy is cached in the multitenant container, you *can't maintain state*. This is super important because you will run into tons of threading issues.

```cs
public class TenantResolverStrategy : ITenantIdentificationStrategy
{
  public TenantResolverStrategy(
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
    IMemoryCache memoryCache,
    TenantEntity tenantEntity
  )
  {
    this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    this.memoryCache = memoryCache;

    // PROBLEM! Where is TenantEntity coming from?
    this.tenantEntity = tenantEntity;
  }

  public bool TryIdentifyTenant(out object tenantId)
  {
    tenantId = null;

    var context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    var hostName = context?.Request?.Host.Value;

    // PROBLEM: Incorrectly storing state in the strategy
    // when this is used across threads. (There's also no
    // explanation of what's in GetTenant, so it's hard to
    // help with that.) 
    tenantEntity = GetTenant(hostName);
    if (tenantEntity != null)
    {
      tenantId = tenantEntity.TenantCode;
    }

    return (tenantId != null || tenantId == (object)"");
  }
}
```

**You can maintain a cache, but don't maintain state.** For example, maybe you need a `Dictionary<string, object>` to cache hostname to tenant ID mappings, and that's fine (as long as you do locking around that, or use a thread-safe dictionary). But you have a *single object* that can be overwritten across threads and that's bad news.

Next, I see your tenant ID strategy takes dependencies. *Generally, I'd avoid this and construct it directly.* I know that's not great for some folks, but there is a tendency to "over-DI" things that shouldn't be involved in DI. Manually constructing base objects like a `ContainerBuilder` or your tenant ID strategy ensures you're only looking at things that you can control (and it avoids these exceptions like you've seen).

**You should be able to manually resolve any dependencies that go into the tenant ID strategy.** For example, this should work:

```cs
public static MultitenantContainer ConfigureMultitenantContainer(IContainer container)
{
  // These are the dependencies of the strategy. You don't NEED TO DO THIS
  // but if you put these in here, it SHOULD NOT BLOW UP. If it does, you know
  // where to start tracing things down.
  var accessor = container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>();
  var cache = container.Resolve<IMemoryCache>();
  var entity = container.Resolve<TenantEntity>();

  // Here's the strategy - again, make sure it's a SINGLETON!
  var strategy = container.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
  var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(strategy, container);
  // mtc.ConfigureTenant("a", cb => cb.RegisterType<TenantACustom>().As<ITenantCustom>());
  return mtc;
}
```

That said, I recognize that things like database connections may need to be injected, in which case, again, be sure things are marked as *singletons*. Your multitenant container tenant ID strategy will live for the lifetime of the application. Plus, nothing that depends on a tenant ID strategy (like the multitenant container) should be tenant-specific or request-based because... you can't determine the tenant without a valid tenant ID strategy. Circular dependency!

So, boiling it all down:

- Register your tenant ID strategy as a singleton.
- Remove all dependencies in the tenant ID strategy that aren't singletons (e.g., `TenantEntity`).
- Use thread-safe caching (e.g., the memory cache) for host-to-tenant-ID mappings, but do not store state (don't keep that `TenantEntity` instance variable; make it a method-level local variable if you need to).
- Make sure everything you need to resolve is registered. If your tenant ID strategy needs `IHttpContextAccessor` (or `IMemoryCache`, or whatever) that needs to be registered. Try resolving those dependencies directly if you run into trouble; that will tell you exactly which component is having problems. (However, if you look through the full stack trace of the exception you're getting, you should see exactly what's going on. You didn't include that exception message in the question, so we can't dive in.)

Comment: I couldn't resolve any classes related to DbContextOption. Other than that is resolvable. I need to get the tenant information based on hostname includes connection string. The exception message I got is `An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll: 'An exception was thrown while activating WebApi.Saas.TenantResolverStrategy2 -> Data.System.Databases.SystemDbContext -> λ:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions[[Data.System.Databases.SystemDbContext, Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]`

Comment: Did you register the "DbContextOption?" You need to register _everything you want to resolve_.

Comment: I am able to resolve DbContext and DbContextOption outside/after the ConfigureMultitenantContainer.

Comment: There's not enough here to help you. We can't see from your code where DbContextOption is registered. It doesn't matter, though, it boils down to this: If you can't resolve it from the container at the time you resolve your strategy, it's not registered correctly. Maybe it's not registered soon enough, maybe it depends on some sort of multitenant support, maybe it's registered incorrectly as instance-per-request, could be a LOT of different things. That's the problem you have to solve since there's not enough here for anyone to help. Good luck!

Comment: I have resolved it by simplifying the ITenantIdentificationStrategy and remove DbContext related classes. And make Tenant injectable on separate container register. Thanks for your highlight those points which could be potential issue.

Comment: If this helps, please come back and accept my answer so I get credit for helping. Thanks!